# OpenCV c++ assertion failed <i < 0> in cv::_InputArray::getMat

Tags: c++, opencv, assertion

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

//initial min and max HSV filter values.
//these will be changed using trackbars    


Mat src; Mat HSV; Mat roi; Mat range; Mat eroded; Mat gray;
int thresh = 100;
int max_thresh = 255;

/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    createTrackbars();
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;


    namedWindow("background", 1);

    int waitTime = 50;
    int counter = 101;

    int roiLeft = 20;
    int roiTop = 50;
    int roiRight = 200;
    int roiBottom = 200;
    Rect rRoi = Rect(roiLeft, roiTop, roiRight, roiBottom);

    Mat background;
    cap >> background;
    background = background(rRoi);
    //cvtColor(background, background, CV_BGR2HSV);

    //imshow("background", background);


    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<vector < cv::Point >> hull(1);
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    vector<CvConvexityDefect> defects;

    while (true)
    {
        cap >> src;

        //Create the region of interest.
        Mat iRoi = src.clone()(rRoi);
        Mat iRoiSRC = src(rRoi);

        //Draw a rectangle there.
        rectangle(src, rRoi, Scalar(255, 128, 0), 1, 8, 0);
        //imshow("roi", iRoi);

        //Subtract the static background.
        absdiff(iRoi, background, iRoi);
        //imshow("diff", iRoi);

        //Convert it to a GrayScale and threshold it.
        cvtColor(iRoi, iRoi, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        threshold(iRoi, gray, 15, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        //Perform a closing.
        Mat erodeElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(erodeSize, erodeSize));
        Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(dilateSize, dilateSize));
        for (int index = 0; index < loopAmount; index++)
        {
            erode(gray, gray, erodeElement);
            dilate(gray, gray, dilateElement);
        }
        //imshow("range", gray);


        //Find the contours.
        findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

        //Pick the biggest contour.
        int biggestContourIndex = 0;
        int largestArea = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            if (contours[i].size() > largestArea)
            {
                largestArea = contours[i].size();
                biggestContourIndex = i;
            }
        }


        vector<int> hullsI;
        vector<Point> hullsP;
        vector<Vec4i> defects;


        //Find the convex hull.
        if (contours.size() > 0)
        {
            convexHull(contours[biggestContourIndex], hullsI, true, true);
            convexHull(contours[biggestContourIndex], hullsP, true, true);
        }

        //Find the convexity defects.
        if (contours.size() > 0)
        {
            if (contours[biggestContourIndex].size() > 3)
            {               
                convexityDefects(contours[biggestContourIndex], hullsI, defects);               
            }
        }




        //Draw the biggest contour and its convex hull.
        Scalar colorOne = Scalar(255, 128, 0);
        Scalar colorTwo = Scalar(0, 0, 255);
        if (contours.size() > 0)
        {
            drawContours(iRoiSRC, contours, biggestContourIndex, colorOne, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
            drawContours(iRoiSRC, hullsP, 0, colorTwo, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point());
            rectangle(iRoiSRC, boundingRect(contours[biggestContourIndex]), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0);

        }
        imshow("src", src);

        if (waitKey(waitTime) >= 0) break;

    }

    return(0);
}
```

There is a rectangle in the upper left of the screen, where my hand will be recognized once I hold it there.

The error that i get appears at the first `drawContours`. The full error which is given to me by the console is: `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed <i <0> in cv::_InputArray::getMat, file C:\buildslave64\win64_amdoc1\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc11-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 963`

I've been extensively searching for a solution on multiple sites, including stackoverflow but none of the solution seem to be working.

Any help would be appreciated.

I use Visual studio 2013 with OpenCV-2.4.10

Comment: Did you debug stepping through the code, to see where the negative value of `i` actually comes from?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes but I couldn't find the value.

Comment: can you print biggestContourIndex before the function call? btw, contour.size() isnt the area of the contour but the number of points!

Comment: @Micka biggestContourIndex = 1 every time since it does detect my hand as the biggest area. 

And I will change the variable name. would be unclear. thank you!

Comment: are you 100% sure that the error occurs in the FIRST drawContours? can you try to replace vector<Vec4i>() by noArray() in the 2nd call?

Comment: Well, the error states that the second drawContours would be called after the thread returns from the current function so I would conclude that the error occurs in the first drawContours. If I set vector<Vec4i>() to noArray() it does run but then the error occurs at 'rectangle' below it. and if i comment that out (just to see if it would show) the error shifts to imshow().

Comment: if you comment out the whole drawContours block everything works fine?

Comment: Turns out vector<CvConvexityDefect> defects; needed to be converted to a point vector and now it works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

converting `vector<CvConvexityDefect> defects;` to a point seemed to do the trick